# Mobius transformation from upper plane onto the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, analytic-functions

> > Let $H =\{ z = x +iy \in \mathbb C : y>0 \}$ and $D = \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z| <1\}$ be the open unit disc . Suppose $f$ is a mobius transformation which maps conformaly onto $D$. Suppose that $f(2i) = 0$. Pick each correct statement from below.
> >
> > $1.$ $\ f$ has a simple  pole at  $z = -2i$.
> >
> > $2.$ $\ f$ satisfies $f(i)\overline{f(-i)} = 1$
> >
> > $3.$ $\ f$  has essential singularity at $z = -2i$
> >
> > $4.$ $\ |f(2+2i)| = \frac{1}{\sqrt5}$

I know that any analytic function from $H$ onto $D$ is of the  form $f(z) = e^{i\theta}\frac{z-z_o}{z-\bar z_o}$, where $z_o$ is the zeroes of $f$, so $f(z) = e^{i\theta}\frac{z-2i}{z-\overline 2i}$,,  thus $f(z) = e^{i\theta}\frac{z-2i}{z+2i}$. Thus $f$ has a simple pole at  $z = -2i$. So 1) is true and 3) is false.

Now $f(i) =  \frac{-e^{i\theta}}{3}$ and $f(-i) =  -3e^{i\theta}$

Therefore $f$ satisfies $f(i)\overline{f(-i)} = 1$, so 2) is also true.

for 4) $|f(2 +2i)| = |\frac{2}{2 +4i}| = \frac{1}{\sqrt 5} $

I would be  thankful if someone check my solution.

Comment: Mobious would mean of or related to Moby https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby

Comment: Sorry, this is a writting mistake , i have changed

Comment: @ Will :Sir this is an exam question , I wnt to know that my solution is right or not, specially for 2nd option.